# Convert λ-expressions to SK-expressions

Tags: code-golf, string, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

The [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Formal_definition), or lambda calculus, is a logical system based on anonymous functions. For example, this a λ-expression:

```
λf.(λx.xx)(λx.f(xx))
```

However, for the purposes of this challenge, we'll simplify the notation:

- Change `λ` to `\` (to make it easier to type): `\f.(\x.xx)(\x.f(xx))`
- The `.` in lambda headers is unnecessary, so we can drop it: `\f(\xxx)(\xf(xx))`
- Use the [Unlambda](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unlambda)-style prefix notation with `` ` `` for application rather than writing the two functions together (for a full explanation of how to do this, see [Convert between Lambda Calculus Notations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110011/61384)): `` \f`\x`xx\x`f`xx ``
- This is the most complicated substitution. Replace each variable with a number in brackets based on how deeply nested the variable is relative to the lambda header it belongs to (i.e. use 0-based [De Bruijn indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index)). For example, in `\xx` (the identity function), the `x` in the body would be replaced with `[0]`, because it belongs to the first (0-based) header encountered when traversing the expression from the variable to the end; ``` \x\y``\x`xxxy ``` would be converted into ``` \x\y``\x`[0][0][1][0] ```. We can now drop the variables in the headers, leaving ``` \\``\`[0][0][1][0] ```.

Combinatory logic is basically a [Turing Tarpit](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit) made out of the λ-calculus (Well, actually, it came first, but that's irrelevant here.)

"Combinatory logic can be viewed as a variant of the lambda calculus, in which lambda expressions (representing functional abstraction) are replaced by a limited set of combinators, primitive functions from which bound variables are absent."<sup>1</sup>

The most common type of combinatory logic is the [SK combinator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), which uses the following primitives:

```
K = λx.λy.x
S = λx.λy.λz.xz(yz)
```

Sometimes a combinator `I = λx.x` is added, but it is redundant, as `SKK` (or indeed `SKx` for any `x`) is equivalent to `I`.

All you need is K, S, and application to be able to encode any expression in the λ-calculus. As an example, here's a translation from the function `λf.(λx.xx)(λx.f(xx))` to combinatory logic:

```
λf.(λx.xx)(λx.f(xx)) = S(K(λx.xx))(λf.λx.f(xx))
λx.f(xx) = S(Kf)(S(SKK)(SKK))
λf.λx.f(xx) = λf.S(Kf)(S(SKK)(SKK))
λf.S(Sf)(S(SKK)(SKK)) = S(λf.S(Sf))(K(S(SKK)(SKK)))
λf.S(Sf) = S(KS)S
λf.λx.f(xx) = S(S(KS)S)(K(S(SKK)(SKK)))
λx.xx = S(SKK)(SKK)
λf.(λx.xx)(λx.f(xx)) = S(K(S(SKK)(SKK)))(S(S(KS)S)(K(S(SKK)(SKK))))
```

Since we are using the prefix notation, this is ```` ```S`K``S``SKK``SKK``S``S`KSS`K``SKK` ````.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Combinatory_logic_in_computing)</sub>

### The Challenge

By now, you've probably guessed what is: Write a program that takes a valid λ-expression (in the notation described above) as input and outputs (or returns) the same function, rewritten in SK-combinator calculus. Note that there are an infinite number of ways to rewrite this; you only need to output one of the infinite ways.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submission (measured in bytes) wins.

### Test Cases

Each test case shows one possible output. The expression on top is the equivalent λ-calculus expression.

````
λx.x:
\[0]                        -> ``SKK
λx.xx:
\`[0][0]                    -> ```SKK``SKK
λx.λy.y:
\\[0]                       -> `SK
λx.λy.x:
\\[1]                       -> K
λx.λy.λz.xz(yz):
\\\``[2][0]`[1][0]          -> S
λw.w(λx.λy.λz.xz(yz))(λx.λy.x):
\``[0]\\[1]\\\``[2][0]`[1][0] -> ``S``SI`KS`KK
````

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/105991/56725

Comment: I think your second test case is not correct. The last contains a number not in brackets.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53250/134

Comment: How did you get `λx.f(xx) = S(Kf)(SKK)`? Shouldn't it rather be `λx.f(xx) = S(Kf)(SII) = S(Kf)(S(SKK)(SKK))`? When converting `λx.f(xx)`, I get `S {λx.f} {λx.xx}` which reduces to `S (Kf) {λx.xx}` and the expression in brackets is nothing else than `ω=λx.xx`, which we know is represented as `SII = S(SKK)(SKK)`, right?

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc Right, I meant `SII`, not `SKK`. That was a mistake.

Comment: For the last test case input `\\`\`[0]\\[1]\\\\`\`[2][0]\`[1][0]`, wouldn't the equivalent lambda expression be `λw.w(λx.λy.x)(λx.λy.λz.xz(yz))` instead of `λw.w(λx.λy.λz.xz(yz))(λx.λy.x)`? In other words, isn't `\\`\`[0]EF` equivalent to `λw.wEF` instead of to `λw.wFE`?

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, <s>251 237 222</s> 214 bytes

15 bytes saved thanks to @Ørjan_Johansen (also see his TIO links in the remarks)!

8 more bytes saved thanks to @nimi!

```
data E=S|K|E:>E|V Int
p(h:s)|h>'_',(u,a)<-p s,(v,b)<-p u=(v,a:>b)|h>'['=a<$>p s|[(n,_:t)]<-reads s=(t,V n)
a(e:>f)=S:>a e:>a f
a(V 0)=S:>K:>K
a(V n)=K:>V(n-1)
a x=K:>x
o(e:>f)='`':o e++o f
o S="S"
o K="K"
f=o.snd.p
```

`p` parses the input, returning the remaining unparsed part in the first component of the resulting pair. The first character of its argument must be a backtick, a backslash or an opening bracket. The pattern guards of `p` check these cases in this order. In the first case, denoting an application, two more expressions are parsed and combined to an element of the `E` data type with the infix constructor `:>`. In the lambda case, the following expression is parsed and immediately given to the `a` function. Otherwise it is a variable, we get its number with the `reads` function (which returns a list) and drop the closing bracket by pattern matching with `(_:t)`.

The `a` function does the quite well known bracket abstraction. To abstract an application, we abstract the two subexpressions and use the `S` combinator to distribute the argument to both. This is always correct, but with more code we could [do much better](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/105991/56725) by handling special cases in order to get shorter expressions. Abstracting the current variable gives `I` or, when we don't have that, `SKK`. Usually the remaining cases can just add a `K` to the front, but when using this notation we have to renumber the variables as the inner lambda is abstracted.

`o` turns the result to a string for output. `f` is the complete function.

As in many languages, backslash is an escape character, so it has to be given twice in a string literal:

```
*Main> f "\\[0]"
"``SKK"
*Main> f "\\`[0][0]"
"``S``SKK``SKK"
*Main> f "\\\\[0]"
"``S``S`KS`KK`KK"
*Main> f "\\\\[1]"
"``S`KK``SKK"
*Main> f "\\\\\\``[2][0]`[1][0]"
"``S``S`KS``S``S`KS``S`KK`KS``S``S`KS``S``S`KS``S`KK`KS``S``S`KS``S`KK`KK``S`KK``SKK``S``S`KS``S``S`KS``S`KK`KS``S`KK`KK``S`KK`KK``S``S`KS``S``S`KS``S`KK`KS``S``S`KS``S`KK`KK``S``S`KS`KK`KK``S``S`KS``S``S`KS``S`KK`KS``S`KK`KK``S`KK`KK"
```

Comment: 1. On the second line, you can use `(a,(b,v))<-p<$>p s`. 2. The `'\\'` can be just `_` if you move that match last.

Comment: Actually, scratch the first part: It's shorter to swap the tuple order and use `p(_:s)=a<$>p s` for the (moved) `'\\'` line.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#NU7LisMgFN37FZcwUKUmtLOUml0WQ5aBbGIZnalCoNXQmNJF/j29Oh2Qc88TvJnRg4TRR3s3vxE@YPHX0dsZKriZCRzerLeLiQYa2a3t2oi6WXv48pFMdKd3YmYrNXxhp3KCmdMf/sh0kdSIOqnUU@qveP0vYgpJpHDI2UA9p98iMnY@lXdrLnNq9eB5ZMRQK2rHZCdqAzaBQ6@HQ7ZafFl6JpH31JdH3MAzqScJ73H6bQC73wdcB@hk0RV4W1m0BXEyVG6O1bRtajicidKImag3HhMqrYfP5GvUeF4 "Haskell – TIO Nexus") for your current version. Which by the way is only 236 bytes, you can drop the final newline.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#LU5Ni4MwEL3nVwxSaEJV2j0Gk5uHxaPgRUudrhGEbZQmlh7873YSCsP74s0wD5wsKJisN0/883CA1f5P1jjI4YELjMTR7wN6hFLVW7WVUpdbA7/Ws4Uf@6N0YuNriqLIFnApf6X3KFdFEqW@i9BrY6/lNuU36YW4FtnT4ODAKe7TBmxo3aijsDhoOsSQG6lHoWqpEUyAkbIGzjGqaKK1QpFuuM0ugiG8g3uz@bsc/pvBnE4zbc9Qq6ROiCuVVAkb1Zw7O@TLvnft@cq6njCK7ouXgF3ftz8h78kTfQA "Haskell – TIO Nexus") with my suggestions.

Comment: How come all my λ-calculus problems are solved in Haskell? Does it have some λ-expression manipulation capabilities?

Comment: @Challenger5 I think it's mostly due to the fact that haskell is based on lambda calculus, so people proficient in haskell are more likely to be attracted to this kind of questions :)

Comment: @Challenger5 I agree with Leo, plus your sample size is not that big. Stateless parsing doesn't help golfing, a concise notation for algebraic data types does (but that's not used in the other challenge).

Comment: You can define `p` with a single expression with three guards, rearrange the cases and drop a superfluous pair of `()`: `p(h:s)|h>'_',(u,a)<-p s,(v,b)<-p u=(v,a:>b)|h>'['=a<$>p s|[(n,_:t)]<-reads s=(t,V n)`.